# AWS Cloudformation invoke bash script for ec2 user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, aws-cloudformation

I have created a cloudformation template for EC2 instance , that will setup Tomcat in the user data. The template works fine when the script is embedded in the template. But I want to move the script in a separate bash script (named tomcat.sh) and invoke the script using userdata as cfn parameter from the AWS CLI. But getting the error

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name EC2Instance2 --template-url s3://cfn04012021/14-01-CFN-EC2-Instance2.yml --parameters ParameterKey=UserData,ParameterValue=$(base64 -w0 tomcat)

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: -w0, tomcat)
```

The cloudformation template is as follows

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: EC2 Instance with Instance profile role to access S3 buckets

Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Key name to SSH to VM's. 
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  UserData:
    Type: String
    Default: ""

  MyStageVMInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0533f2ba8a1995cf9
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref MySecurityGroup
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref MyInstanceProfile
      Tags:
        - Key: Name        
          Value: dev
      UserData: !Ref UserData
```

the bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash|
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
sudo groupadd --system tomcat 
sudo useradd -d /usr/share/tomcat -r -s /bin/false -g tomcat tomcat
getent passwd tomcat
getent group tomcat
export VER="9.0.41"
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v${VER}/bin/apache-tomcat-${VER}.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf apache-tomcat-${VER}.tar.gz -C /usr/share/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/apache-tomcat-$VER/ /usr/share/tomcat
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/tomcat
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/apache-tomcat-$VER/ 
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service<<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/share/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M'
ExecStart=/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start tomcat
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```

Comment: What platform and shell are you running that aws cli command on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 to run cloudformation using AWS CLI

Comment: Windows 10's cmd doesn't support the `$()` syntax from bash.  I know of no way to do something equivalent.  Personally, I'd look into scripting with WSL if you're on Windows 10, but perhaps someone else knows a cmd specific answer.

Comment: Also:  Your script has an extra `|` on the `#!` line.

Comment: The error is from `base64 -w0 tomcat` "Unknown options: -w0, tomcat)"